# How can i increase the client_max_body_size for a Aws Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I had deployed an application on EKS, and tried two ways of exposing it for traffic. though ingress is a better approach, I also tried directly exposing the application through a LB.

1. Load Balancer: When I exposed a service directly through a load balancer, it was unable to receive file sizes greater then 20MB, I was having trouble finding out a way to configure the loadbalancer or the kubernetes service to accept a file of that size. I was always getting "413 Request Entity Too Large Error". Is there a way to configure the LB to accept file sizes more than a specific limit?
2. Using ingress through nginx-ingress: I was able to configure nginx-ingress to accept file size greater than 25 MB and my application was working properly.

Comment: I suggest reaching out to AWS support to get some details, because I wasn't able to find any even references to this parameter or limits about it. And later you [can answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with their response because it will be useful for the community.

Comment: Do you found any solution?

Comment: comment from aws support - Regarding your query, I have checked with my internal ELB Team and would like to inform you that, "ALB does not have any maximum payload size limit unless the target is a Lambda function." Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In my case we were using Hapi server(similar to express servers) behind an ALB. we were getting

> 'statusCode: 413 Request Entity Too Large. Payload content length greater than maximum allowed: 5000000'

Initially we thought it was because of the ALB payload size restriction but it turned out that our server was configured to reject requests with payload greater than 5MB. So we increased the "**maxBytes**" key in the server configuration and it started working. So I would suggest to look into the server config.